# How to pad and normalize variable length arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have the following chart array which contains the foo, bar and baz objects, each object contains a values array with the data points.

The problem is that from my API endpoint I get a variable amount of data points.
And I need to normalize my objects so they:

- The datapoints need to be sorted by the label acending (eg. a, b, c..)
- If the data point does not exist, in a particular object but exists,
  in any other array of data points, it's generated with a value of zero
- At the end, the number of data points in each object must be the same.

Here's an example of the code:

```
var r = function() { return Math.random() * 10; };

var chart = [
    {key:'foo', values: [['a', r()], ['b', r()], ['c', r()], ['d', r()]]},
    {key:'bar', values: [['b', r()], ['c', r()], ['d', r()], ['e', r()]]},
    {key:'baz', values: [['c', r()], ['d', r()], ['e', r()], ['f', r()]]}
];

// desired output, where x is the random value returned by r()
// any values that are unavailable must be 0
chart = [
    {key:'foo', values: [['a', x], ['b', x], ['c', x], ['d', x], ['e', 0], ['f', 0]]},
    {key:'bar', values: [['a', 0], ['b', x], ['c', x], ['d', x], ['e', x], ['f', 0]]},
    {key:'baz', values: [['a', 0], ['b', 0], ['c', x], ['d', x], ['e', x], ['f', x]]}
];
```

Comment: I tried iterating through each data point and checking it it exists in the other value arrays. But it resulted in an unholy mess of for loops. I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stay in order'? If foo had a, c and e and bar had b, d, and f...what order do you expect the resulting data points to be in?

Comment: I updated the question. The values array needs to be sorted by the fist item of each data point. `[['a',x], ... ['z',x]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your letter–number pairs might be better represented by objects rather than arrays, but nevertheless I believe this solves the question as stated.

```
var datapointLabels = {};                                 // Create object to record which labels exist. 
for(var i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {                   // Iterate through `chart` items.
  for(var j = 0; j < chart[i].values.length; j++) {       // Iterate through `values` items.
    var datapointLabel = chart[i].values[j][0];
    datapointLabels[datapointLabel] = true;
  }
}
// Skip nested loops above if datapoint labels are pre-known; construct `datapointsLabels` object with one loop, or manually without looping, instead.

var newChart = [];                                        // Must create a new array to hold the padded data (will need to refer to old array throughout process).
for(var i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {
  newChart[i] = {};
  newChart[i].key = chart[i].key;
  newChart[i].values = [];
  for(var datapointLabel in datapointLabels) {            // Iterate through all datapoint labels in our records object.
    var datapoint = 0;                                    // Set default datapoint as zero.
    for(var j = 0; j < chart[i].values.length; j++) {     // Look at each `value` pair to see if it matches the current datapoint label.
      if(chart[i].values[j][0] === datapointLabel) {
        datapoint = chart[i].values[j][1];                // Overwrite default if found.
        j = chart[i].values.length;                       // Skip further checks (optional, minor efficiency increase).
      }
    }
    newChart[i].values.push([datapointLabel, datapoint]); // Push found or default data to new array.
  }  
}
```

[image]

If you *are* able to redefine your data structure, here's a way to cut a `for`-loop, using object-key lookup:

```
var chart = [
  { key: 'foo', values: { a: r(), b: r(), c: r(), d: r() } },
  { key: 'bar', values: { b: r(), c: r(), d: r(), e: r() } },
  { key: 'baz', values: { c: r(), d: r(), e: r(), f: r() } }
];

var datapointLabels = {};                                 // Create object to record which labels exist. 
for(var i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {                   // Iterate through `chart` items.
  for(var datapointLabel in chart[i].values){             // Iterate through `values` items.
    datapointLabels[datapointLabel] = true;
  }
}
// Skip nested loops above if datapoint labels are pre-known; construct `datapointsLabels` object with one loop, or manually without looping, instead.

var newChart = [];                                        // Must create a new array to hold the padded data (will need to refer to old array throughout process).
for(var i = 0; i < chart.length; i++) {
  newChart[i] = {};
  newChart[i].key = chart[i].key;
  newChart[i].values = {};
  for(var datapointLabel in datapointLabels) {            // Iterate through all datapoint labels in records object.
    var datapoint = chart[i].values[datapointLabel] || 0;
    newChart[i].values[datapointLabel] = datapoint;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and the comments you just added), it works and it's better that what I had, but do you think there is a way to avoid so many `for` loops using `Array.map()`?

Comment: Perhaps, but I believe it would amount only to a stylistic choice between imperative and functional paradigms. `Array.map` might prove more pleasing to some eyes; it might also prove to run a hair more slowly.

Comment: The weakness I see above is the multiple iterations over the same arrays, which could be reduced if the data sets were instead stored and referenced by object keys (my 'letter–number' note). But I realize that could mean a loss of hours redesigning that part of the app. Developer time counts, too.

Comment: Isn't just stylistic. Your code has 5 iterations, but with `Array.map()` you can solve it just with 3 or less.

Comment: @jkutianski – What goes on under the hood of `Array.map`? Is it similar to Underscore's `map`? I myself don't know.

Comment: `Array.map()` is like a mutation. The function iterate the Array and replace the value on this index position with the return of the function. Is very common see `Array.map()` with `Array.reduce()`.
[MDN Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Of course `Array.map` hides at least one iteration. And check out MDN's equivalent polyfill—yowza! I won't deny `map`'s great at cutting characters, but I've seen others debate its efficiency before. I, again, am unsure.

Comment: Also note that the first two of those five loops are for constructing an object that is assumed to be unknown. If it is known, the two can be collapsed into one or even none.

Comment: This is the best answer, although I wish this was more concise, but the loops couldn't be avoided. It runs great, here's a graph that was generated with your algorithm. [Graph](http://snag.gy/kUETL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

My solution using `Array.map()`.

```
var temp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var newchart = chart.map(function (obj) {
    var objValKeys = obj.values.map(function (objVal) {
        return objVal[0];
    });
    return {
        key: obj.key,
        values: temp.map(function (thisval) {
            var index = objValKeys.indexOf(thisval);
            var actlVal = (index+1) ? obj.values[index][1] : 0;
            return [thisval, actlVal];
        })
    };
});
```

Check it on [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/EL2qU/)

Comment: This code assumes all datapoint labels are pre-known. Not sure if that's allowed in OP's app, but worth noting.

Comment: Its style is more sophisticated. I'm unconvinced of its efficiency (three `map`s). But still, cheers.